# Inexplicable MVC model data alteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model that is essentially an object that contains a list of objects that have three numeric fields and one string field, similar to the following:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public List<DataItemModel> DataItems { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
}
```

The View has a table that allows the user to set each item's `Value` and `Comment` fields (`ID` is generated by the data layer and `IntegerValue` is derived from `Value`). The user can add and delete items from the collection via AJAX, using the jQuery `post()` method, with the webpage being partially updated using `html()`.

The issue I'm seeing is if I have a list of Comment/Value pairs like so:

```
Item 1, 1.00
Item 2, 2.00
Item 3, 3.00
Item 4, 4.00
Item 5, 5.00
```

And I delete the third item via the webpage, the Controller correctly changes the data to:

```
Item 1, 1.00
Item 2, 2.00
Item 4, 4.00
Item 5, 5.00
```

And returns the new HTML using `PartialView()`. But when the webpage is updated, the model is somehow transformed to be:

```
Item 1, 1.00
Item 2, 2.00
Item 3, 3.00
Item 4, 4.00
```

I have confirmed this using VS2013's debugger and Firefox's network packet analyser thing, but am completely at a loss as to how or why this happens. I don't think it's a caching issue, as the jQuery docs say that `post()` never caches by definition. I guess it has something to do witht he call to `PartialView()`?

**Edit:** The (partial) View in question is simply a table inside an HTML form, which is placed inside a `div` using jQuery's `html()` method.

**Update:** I've done some more debugging, and have managed to eliminate the call to `PartialView()` being at fault; it's definitely returning a correctly formed `PartialViewResult`.

Comment: May we see the relevant part of your `View`?

Comment: Index is usually zero based, so the third item is `2` not `3`.  Please add the relevant delete javascript and c# code.

Comment: I've verified I'm passing the right indexes already, so I know that's not the issue

Comment: How the PartialView getting data?

Is it pulling data from Database before you delete the record from Database?

Comment: No, but as I've just posted below, I've found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can fix the whole shebang by calling `ModelState.Clear()` at the beginning of the Controller method. I have no idea why it works, all I know is adding that one line has fixed the issue.